# What is the first programming language where the keyword "new" appeared?

Tags: programming-languages, history

It's really interesting when this keyword first appeared as a lot of popular languages but relatively old languages( C++, C#, Java, JS ) use it. I understand use of "new" in C++ in practical manner( stack vs heap ). But i don't understand it in Java, Js, C# where all objects( except C# structs ) are created on heap by default.

Comment: I think it appeared in [Simula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) ([example](https://web.archive.org/web/20040923044248/http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/bookhtml/chap09.html)). [C++ got it from Simula (§2.4.1)](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf). Once C++ had made it popular, other languages such as Java and C# took it.

Comment: (Even as it was renamed Simula in the '80s, the standard is still out in the wild, see [object-generator](http://simula67.at.ifi.uio.no/Standard-86/chap_3.htm).)